# Rails ArgumentError "Unknown Key"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

So I have a Rails app in which users can create 'submissions'. Now I'm trying to add the ability to create folders in which submissions will be, for organization. However, I've seem to have run into an issue getting the Folder model working. I'm getting the following error:

```
Unknown key: #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f17cc75d498>
```

The error says it's on line 21 in this code:

```
18:                 </div>
19: 
20:                 <div id="submission-list-container">
21:                     <% current_user.folders.each do |i| %>
22:                         <a href='#'>
23:                             <div id="post-container">
24:                                 <%= i.title %> <p id="created-time">Created <%= i.created_at.strftime("%e/%-m") %></p>
```

I created the Folder model using `rails g model folder title:string` and my model looks like this:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title, :user_id

belongs_to :user
has_many :submissions, order => ('updated_at DESC')
end
```

My guess is that I might have set up the relationship between users, submissions, and folders incorrectly. Here are my user and submission models:

submission.rb:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :folder
belongs_to :user


attr_accessible :content, :title, :user_id


end
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :user_id,  :submissions, :folders
# attr_accessible :title, :body

has_many :submissions
has_many :folders, through: :submissions

end
```

Also my migrations dir look like this:

```
20130523233304_create_submissions.rb
20130530064506_devise_create_users.rb
20130621002458_add_user_id_to_submissions.rb
20130709213421_add_user_id_to_folders.rb
20130710042650_add_folder_id_to_submissions.rb
20130710200424_create_folders.rb
```

Any idea what could be wrong? This is my first time experiencing this error, so I'm unsure what I've fudged up.

**Edit**
Here's are the Schema.rb tables for folders and submissions:

```
create_table "folders", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "submissions", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "content"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

**Edit 2**
My create_folders migration:

```
class CreateFolders < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :folders do |t|
    t.string :title

  t.timestamps
end
```

end
end

And here is my add_folder_id_to_submissions migration file:

```
class AddFolderIdToSubmissions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you add `user_id` and `folder_id` columns to the Submissions table?

Comment: I did perform migrations for that, as you can see above (and yes, I used rake db:migrate afterwards). Do I need to go into the migrations and add/modify any code?

Comment: Now I get the error message from Postgres which makes me think that folder_id still hasn't been added to submissions table: PG::Error: ERROR:  column submissions.folder_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ers" INNER JOIN "submissions" ON "folders"."id" = "submissio...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "folders".* FROM "folders" INNER JOIN "submissions" ON "folders"."id" = "submissions"."folder_id" WHERE "submissions"."user_id" = 2

Comment: Do I need to log into my Postgres database and add the folder_id column?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be necessary. Could you post your Schema (just the relevant tables) as well as the actual code from the migration files?

Comment: Also, have you restarted the server since you've made these migrations? Do it again just to be safe :)

Comment: Okay, I've restarted my server (didn't help) and posted the submissions and folders schema tables. Maybe I need to just added a column in the submissions table for folder_id?

Comment: Ran the rails console and it doesn't show folder_id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33231/discussion-between-tom-maxwell-and-mmichael)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few typos which may (or may not) be causing this exception:

```
# app/models/folder.rb
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :submissions, :order => ('updated_at DESC') # note the `:` prior to `order` (denotes a symbol)
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :folders, :through => :submissions
    # or `has_many :folders, through: submissions`
end
```

If you're concerned that a table is missing a column that's included in your migration, you can re-run the migration from command line:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20130710042650
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20130710042650 # runs 20130710042650_add_folder_id_to_submissions.rb
```

Be sure to restart your server after running a migration to get the new content loaded into your environment.

**UPDATE**:

To generate a migration that explicitly adds `folder_id` to submissions, run the following command:

```
rails generate migration AddFolderIdToSubmission folder_id:integer
```

Then, run `rake db:migrate` and restart.

Comment: Thanks for the help cleaning those up! Didn't fix it, but got me closer. Now I'm getting a Postgres error which makes me believe that folder_id hasn't been added to the submissions table. 

PG::Error: ERROR:  column submissions.folder_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ers" INNER JOIN "submissions" ON "folders"."id" = "submissio...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "folders".* FROM "folders" INNER JOIN "submissions" ON "folders"."id" = "submissions"."folder_id" WHERE "submissions"."user_id" = 2

Comment: Not sure if I need to log into my Postgres database to make those changes or I can do it with migrations.

Comment: You should be making DB modifications via migrations, if possible. You can verify whether the `folder_id` column exists by running `rails console` from command line and typing `Submission`. If `folder_id` has been correctly migrated, it'll show up as an attribute of the model.

Comment: Looks like it hasn't migrated properly. I'll update my post with code from the migration files.

Comment: Have you tried to run `db:migrate:up` as depicted in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your use of the bare word `order`, instead of `:order`, on this line:

```
has_many :submissions, order => ('updated_at DESC')
```

`order` is a method which returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, think `Folder.order(:id)...`. You're trying to use that returned object as a key in a hash. This is the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

As determined through the discussion, the issue was that the Submissions table did not have the `folder_id` column. Tom generated an empty migration for adding the `folder_id` to the Submissions table and thus got an ActiveRecord::Relation error.

After generating a new migration that added `folder_id` to the Submissions table, raking the database, and restarting the server, Tom stated the error was resolved.

Check out [Rails Guides on DB migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for more info.